# npm install odbc fails on macOS Sierra(Version 10.12.6)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, electron, macos-sierra

I'm having an issue install the odbc package on macOS Sierra(Version 10.12.6)

I have unixODBC installed on macOS Sierra(Version 10.12.6)

**Here is the output of issuing "npm install odbc"**:

> odbc@1.3.0 install /Users/cspc106/Documents/app/node_modules/odbc
>   node-gyp configure build

2017-12-20 19:11:51.288 xcodebuild[3376:23375] [MT] DVTSDK: Warning: SDK path collision for path '': SDK with name 'watchos4.0' being superceded by SDK with 'watchos4.0'.
2017-12-20 19:11:51.289 xcodebuild[3376:23375] [MT] DVTSDK: Warning: SDK path collision for path '': SDK with name 'iphonesimulator11.0' being superceded by SDK with 'iphonesimulator11.0'.
2017-12-20 19:11:51.290 xcodebuild[3376:23375] [MT] DVTSDK: Warning: SDK path collision for path '': SDK with name 'macosx10.13' being superceded by SDK with 'macosx10.13'.
2017-12-20 19:11:51.291 xcodebuild[3376:23375] [MT] DVTSDK: Warning: SDK path collision for path '': SDK with name 'appletvsimulator11.0' being superceded by SDK with 'appletvsimulator11.0'.
2017-12-20 19:11:51.292 xcodebuild[3376:23375] [MT] DVTSDK: Warning: SDK path collision for path '': SDK with name 'watchsimulator4.0' being superceded by SDK with 'watchsimulator4.0'.
2017-12-20 19:11:51.293 xcodebuild[3376:23375] [MT] DVTSDK: Warning: SDK path collision for path '': SDK with name 'appletvos11.0' being superceded by SDK with 'appletvos11.0'.
2017-12-20 19:11:51.293 xcodebuild[3376:23375] [MT] DVTSDK: Warning: SDK path collision for path '': SDK with name 'iphoneos11.0' being superceded by SDK with 'iphoneos11.0'.
2017-12-20 19:11:51.466 xcodebuild[3376:23375] [MT] DVTPlugInManager: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DF11C142-1584-4A99-87AC-1925D5F5652A for IDEDevkitRefactoring.ideplugin (com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEDevkitRefactoring) not present
2017-12-20 19:11:51.540 xcodebuild[3376:23375] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiOSSupportCore (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiOSSupportCore, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FXPCSessionManager
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FoundationXPC.framework/Versions/A/FoundationXPC
 in /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiOSSupportCore, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiOSSupportCore, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FXPCSessionManager
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FoundationXPC.framework/Versions/A/FoundationXPC
 in /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDEiOSSupportCore” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiOSSupportCore, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FXPCSessionManager
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FoundationXPC.framework/Versions/A/FoundationXPC
 in /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator
2017-12-20 19:11:51.541 xcodebuild[3376:23375] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-13247/IDEFoundation/Initialization/IDEInitialization.m:264
Details:  Xcode failed its initial plug-in scan, error = Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 "Loading a plug-in failed." UserInfo={DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiOSSupportCore, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiOSSupportCore, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiOSSupportCore, 0): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FXPCSessionManager
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FoundationXPC.framework/Versions/A/FoundationXPC
 in /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator, NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in “com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiOSSupportCore” at path “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff0ce6900b0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiOSSupportCore, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FXPCSessionManager
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FoundationXPC.framework/Versions/A/FoundationXPC
 in /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiOSSupportCore, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiOSSupportCore, 265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FXPCSessionManager
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FoundationXPC.framework/Versions/A/FoundationXPC
 in /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “IDEiOSSupportCore” couldn’t be loaded.}}}
Function: BOOL _IDEInitializePlugInManager(IDEInitializationOptions, NSError *__autoreleasing *)
Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
xcodebuild: error: Initialization failed.
    Reason: Loading a plug-in failed.

make: error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 72
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/cspc106/Documents/app/node_modules/odbc
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 (node_modules/bufferutil):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: utf-8-validate@1.2.2 (node_modules/utf-8-validate):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: utf-8-validate@1.2.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! odbc@1.3.0 install: `node-gyp configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the odbc@1.3.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cspc106/.npm/_logs/2017-12-20T13_41_52_231Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that the `make` utility is missing from your system, as you can see here:

> make: error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 72 gyp ERR!

To get that utility on a Mac you'll need to install XCode first. Then you should be able to do that installation without an issue.

As a side note; the command line tools will be required for any NPM packages that use native modules (written in C / C++ and need to be built on an installation).

Comment: XCode is installed on my mac.

Comment: @VimalSharma If you already have XCode installed you'll need to make sure that you also have the command line developer tools installed. Try running this command in your command line: `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Xcode and see if it prompts you with anything. I installed the command line tools several times with no changes in the error message. When I opened Xcode, it prompted me with certain components to install and, when that was complete, the command completed.